# Cannot install Wireless LAN Service on Windows 2012 Server RTM offline

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-server-2012

I'm having trouble installing the Wireless LAN Service offline with a freshly installed Windows 2012 Server RTM.

I tried `install-windowsfeature wireless-networking` in the non-GUI mode and using the server manager in the GUI mode to enable the *Wireless LAN Service*, but both of them show a

> Failure configuring Windows Updates

message after the installation restarted the system.

I checked the event log and I think messages about

> The WLAN Autoconfig service depends on the following service: nativewifip. This service might not be installed

are the source of the issue. Google shows it is a service called *Native WiFi Filter*, but I cannot find anywhere to install that service.

I don't have a Ethernet adapter for that computer, so have to install everything offline before the WiFi's working.

Comment: I remark that my own try at using Windows Server 2012 also ended with an unrecoverable disaster. I suggest waiting for the first service-pack : IMHO the current release is not viable and also Windows Server 2008 R2 is not that bad.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue. I just rebooted tonight, the latest Windows updates were applied and it now works.

So, issued fixed and released by Microsoft on Windows update.